# Setup for Sensing change in concentration of NaCl

Tags: electrochemistry, analytical-chemistry, concentration

I am making a sensor to sense the change in concentration of NaCl. My background is in electronics and chemistry is not my strong area. I got some screen printed electrodes, with Silver (Working Electrode) and Ag/AgCl (Reference Electrode). My initial test is to put the electrodes in separate solutions, with Reference Electrode in a reference solution of known concentration of NaCl and the Working Electrode in the test solution of varying concentration of NaCl. Will this give me a potential difference and will I be able to determine the change in Concentration of NaCl in the working electrode? If not can you make any suggestion on the setup? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I am making a sweat sensor of some sort. This is the first step to show the basic working principles on the sensing aspect.

Answer (score 2):

This will work with the correct set up. You're constructing a galvanic cell, which will result in a cell voltage. The cell voltage will change when you alter the concentration of NaCl on either side. Important though that your two half cells (each side) are connected both electronically and ionically. Do you have a salt bridge or a membrane between them? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_bridge

Comment: Thank you for the info, I do not have a salt bridge. I was not sure what chemical to use for the salt bridge, in my setup. I did a bit of researching on that and KNO3 and KCl look like a strong choice for salt bridge.